# How do I insert an NSTimer within a method?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nstimer

I would like to insert an NSTimer delay within a method and was wondering how to go about doing this. I've bolded where I would like to put the delay timer.

here's my code so far:

```
- (void) buttonPressed:(UIButton*) sender {

for(int i = 0;i < [categoryBtnImages count]; i++)
{
    UIButton *but = (UIButton *)[catButtonArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if(but != sender)
    {
        [but setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[categoryBtnImages objectAtIndex:i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       // but.selected = !but.selected;

    }
}

buttonCat = (UIButton *)sender;
int tagOfButton = buttonCat.tag - 2;

if (tagOfButton == -2 ){
    tagOfButton = 8;
}
[buttonCat setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[categoryBtnImagesSel objectAtIndex:tagOfButton]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**I would like to put the delay here** then run the rest of the code, but all from within this method.

```
if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button 0"]) {
    [self foodCatSort:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button 1"]) {
    [self healthCatSort:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button 2"]) {
    [self shoppingCatSort:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

}

FYI the reason I want to do this is because a button is pressed which reloads the table and the button state image changes. I would like the user to see the uibutton image change first then reload the table. I was thinking a delay would solve this.

Comment: You shouldn't do that, as that will interrupt the main UI thread which will give a bad UI experience.  Instead the delay is effected by doing whatever it is you want doing in the *timer fired* method of the `NSTimer` object.

Comment: Major agreement with trojanfoe on this - never block the UI thread for trivial things. Just use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay - and splitting your methods is not a bad thing. Breaking your work up into logical units of action yields much more readable code, too.

Comment: You can't/shouldn't delay within a method.  You do the first part, then schedule the execution of the second part.

Comment: You can, of course animate the transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a delay you dont need a `NSTimer`.

Use `performselector: withObject: afterDelay:` instead.

Something like this:

```
  [self performSelector:@selector(yourDelayedMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

Comment: but that's calling another method. I was wondering if I could do it within the same method. thanks

Comment: You can't do it within the same method (in the UI thread) and pass Apple tests (or achieve good app operation, for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

I assume the reason you're insisting on both halves being part of the same method is for local variable access. This is in fact possible, just not with an `NSTimer`. To keep the code that you want to delay entirely within the same scope as the original method, you can use `dispatch_after()`:

```
[buttonCat setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[categoryBtnImagesSel objectAtIndex:tagOfButton]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.75 * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button 0"]) {
        [self foodCatSort:nil];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button 1"]) {
        [self healthCatSort:nil];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
    if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Button 2"]) {
        [self shoppingCatSort:nil];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
});
```

You should also probably look into using some kind of animation for this, since an arbitrarily-timed delay between UI effects might seem awkward to the user.